# Codeigniter v2 uppercase file names throwing error "Unable to locate model"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was using codeigniter structure like :
Filename - User,
ControllerClassName - User
ModelClassName - User_model

and hitting url : http://localhost/ci/user
its showing 404 if I hit http://localhost/ci/User its working fine but unable to locate User_model

and if I use Filename as user,user_model instead of User,User_model it works perfectly

**I'm using codeigniter 2**

is there any solution for that issue its not working on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `user` or `User` in the url can not affect model file as that is pointing to controller. It might be other problem.

Comment: no if I rename file it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load the model in `__construct()`

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->load->library('Session');
}
```

---

**In Model**

File name - `user_model.php`
Inside File

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

---

**In Controller**

File name - `user.php`
Inside File

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller
{

}
```